# Databricks Job not able to access notebook from github repository: "Unable to access the notebook ..."

Tags: databricks

I have created a job in Databricks and configured to use a cluster having single user access enabled and using github as a source. When I am trying to run the job, getting following error-

```
run failed with error message Unable to access the notebook "databricks/notebooks/loaders/pubsub_streaming". Either it does not exist, or the identity used to run this job, sumit.desai@abc.com (sumit.desai@abc.com), lacks the required permissions.
```

I have confirmed that the link is correct. Also, I have imported this repo in same databricks environment and can run the corresponding notebook successfully directly (from outside of job)

What permission might be missing here?

Answer (score 2):

The error was occurring because there weren't any headers in the files to treat those as notebooks. Adding following header did the trick-

```
# Databricks notebook source
```

Surprisingly, error message was not conveying anything useful